# How to recognize if app use terminal or Xwindows in Linux

Tags: linux, shell-script, x11

Is posible recognize if application/program run in terminal or in Xwindows window? I want create script which I relay command and it runs this command in terminal if necessary or it runs directly if not necessary.

Details:

I was inspired by [this reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/commandline/comments/jatyek/using_fzf_as_a_dmenurofi_replacement/) and i creaded this scripts:

```bash
#!/bin/zsh
# fzfmenu

kitty zsh -c "fzf $* < /proc/$$/fd/0 > /proc/$$/fd/1"
```

```bash
#!/bin/zsh
# fzflauncher

list=(`echo ${PATH//:/ }`)
exec=()
for dir in $list; do 
    exec+=$(ls $dir)
done

exec `print $exec | fzfmenu`
```

`fzflauncher` finds in all executable files and launch one. If i choice for example terminal game [`bombardier`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/bombardier), program runs without terminal (I don't know how it's possible) and eats 100%CPU.

Comment: Can you please add more detail to your question? What are you trying to do? What is the expected behaviour? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Excuse me please. I added more deteils.